# Apache Continuum does not open Mozzila during selenium testing

Tags: java, selenium, ant

I have little problem continuum. When I try to run ant script from command line then everything work fine. But problem appears when I try to use ant script from continuum. Firefox doesn't want to open, and there is only waiting. Something must blocking but I dont know what.

Here is my ant fragment:

```
<target name="start_selenium" depends="tomcat_start">
    <echo>Starting selenium server</echo>
    <tstamp>
        <format property="TSTAMP" pattern="yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"/>
    </tstamp>
    <java jar="${apl.dir}/eleniumTests/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">           
        <arg line="-firefoxProfileTemplate"/>
        <arg line="/home/local/seleniumFirefox"/>
        <arg line="-htmlSuite"/>
        <arg line="*firefox"/>
        <arg line="http://127.0.0.1:8083/"/>
        <arg line="${apl.dir}/SeleniumTests/suiteTest.html"/>
        <arg line="FirefoxResult.html"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<arg line="...">`, use `<arg value="...">`

```
<java jar="${apl.dir}/eleniumTests/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">           
    <arg value="-firefoxProfileTemplate"/>
    <arg value="/home/local/seleniumFirefox"/>
    <arg value="-htmlSuite"/>
    <arg value="*firefox"/>
    <arg value="http://127.0.0.1:8083/"/>
    <arg value="${apl.dir}/SeleniumTests/suiteTest.html"/>
    <arg value="FirefoxResult.html"/>
</java>
```

Comment: that doesnt help me. Still selenium-server stall at Launch firefox.